# Cell subviews transparency while selected/highlighted

Tags: select, uitableview, highlight

I'd like to know what makes the backgrounds of subviews (labels for example) of a UITableViewCell become transparent while selected/highlighted. I need to avoid that behaviour for some subviews of my content view. I tried overriding the setSelected / setHighlighted methods with some success, but that transparency I wasn't able to reproduce. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I think I got a somewhat close behaviour using the following piece of code

```
- (void) setView:(UIView*) view asHighlighted:(BOOL) highlighted {

    if([view isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]){
        UILabel* label = (UILabel*) view;
        [label setHighlighted:highlighted];
    }

    else if([view isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]){
        UIImageView* imageView = (UIImageView*) view;
        [imageView setHighlighted:highlighted];
    }

    if(highlighted){

        [view.undoManager registerUndoWithTarget:view
                                        selector:@selector(setBackgroundColor:)
                                          object:view.backgroundColor];

        view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    }
    else {
        [view.undoManager undo];
    }

    for(UIView* subview in view.subviews){
        [self setView:subview asHighlighted:highlighted];
    }
}
```

Not sure this is the right way to use UndoManager but it works. You can use this in both setSelected and setHighlighted to mimic selection behaviour of UITableViewCells